# How can i do rescan to hardisk using DDK ?

Tags: wdk

Is it possible to do rescan to some device using the ddk ?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean get the system to rescan for new devices, then you can use devcon.exe utility with the rescan option.

The devcon tool is part of the DDK.

- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311272